# checkbox box with tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

need some help in coding tkinter checkbox.
i am having a check button which if i select, it will enable many other check box. below is the function after selecting the first check box

```
def enable_():
    # Global variables
    global var
    # If Single test
    if (var.get()==1):
        Label (text='Select The Test To Be Executed').grid(row=7,column=1)
        L11 = Label ().grid(row=9,column=1)
        row_me =9
        col_me =0
        test_name_backup = test_name
        for checkBoxName in test_name:
            row_me = row_me+1
            chk_bx = Checkbutton(root, text=checkBoxName, variable =checkBoxName, \
                            onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0, height=1, command=box_select(checkBoxName), \
                            width = 20)
            chk_bx.grid(row = row_me, column = col_me)
            if (row_me == 20):
                row_me = 9
                col_me = col_me+1
```

i have two question here.

1. How to delete the dynamically created check boxes (chk_bx ) i mean if i select the initial check box it will enable many other boxes , if i deselect the first check box it should remove the initially created boxes?
2. How will i get the value from the dynamically creaed box "selected / not"?

Comment: A few observations:  `L11` is `None` since that is what `.grid` returns.  Your Checkbutton command is executed when you create the Checkbutton ... You probably want `lambda name=checkBoxName:box_select(name)`

Comment: you shouldn't use `var` as a variable name... Nor should you use global variables. You can just pass the variable into the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. How to delete the dynamically created check boxes?**

Just add all your checkbuttons to a list, so you can call `destroy()` on them when needed:

```
def remove_checkbuttons():
    # Remove the checkbuttons you want
    for chk_bx in checkbuttons:
        chk_bx.destroy()

def create_checkbutton(name):
    return Checkbutton(root, text=name, command=lambda: box_select(name),
                       onvalue=1, offvalue=0, height=1, width=20)

#...
checkbuttons = [create_checkbutton(name) for name in test_name]
```

**2. How will i get the value from the dynamically creaed box "selected / not"?**

You have to create a Tkinter `IntVar`, which is used to store the `onvalue` or `offvalue` depending on whether the checkbutton is selected or not. You also need to keep track of this object, but it isn't necessary to create a new list, since you can attach them to the corresponding checkbutton:

```
def printcheckbuttons():
    for chk_bx in checkbuttons:
        print chk_bx.var.get()

def create_checkbutton(name):
    var = IntVar()
    cb = Checkbutton(root, variable=var, ...)
    cb.var = var
    return cb
```

Comment: in the def printcheckbuttons():
how do i print which box is selected ?  
for chk_bx in checkbuttons:
  if(chk_bx.var.get()==1):
i want the checkbutton text name to br printed

Comment: Use [`cget`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.cget-method): `print chk_bx.cget('text')`